# Importing inside a website a watson conversation chat

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm implementing a watson conversation chat, now i'm wondering, how i can import this chat in a existing website?

any helps?

Comment: Create a chat UI in your website and then call the Conversation API.

Comment: any tutorials ?

Comment: This should help you https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/develop-app.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see one example [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) in Nodejs **and** [Conversation-with-discovery](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery) in Java.

This repository it is from **IBM Developers**.

This example show one example how to call the API and has some *front-end* for show the *conversation flow* and Watson understands, all you have to know how to use Watson, *context variables*, *intents*, *entities*, etc.

In this case, you call conversation API with **Service Credentials** and Workspace_id from your Conversation created inside IBM Bluemix:

**Example to call and invoke the result with Javascript language (nodejs):**

```
var conversation = new Conversation({
  // If unspecified here, the CONVERSATION_USERNAME and CONVERSATION_PASSWORD env properties will be checked
  // username: '<username>', paste the Service Credentials here or paste in env archive
  // password: '<password>',
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
  version_date: '2016-10-21',
  version: 'v1'
});

// Endpoint to be call from the client side
app.post('/api/message', function(req, res) {
  var workspace = process.env.WORKSPACE_ID || '<workspace-id>'; //workspace id can be check inside Conversation Service, click View details
  if (!workspace || workspace === '<workspace-id>') {
    return res.json({
      'output': {
        'text': 'The app has not been configured with a <b>WORKSPACE_ID</b> environment variable.' //error if workspace_id is not set
      }
    });
  }
  var payload = {
    workspace_id: workspace,
    context: req.body.context || {},
    input: req.body.input || {}
  };

  // Send the input to the conversation service
  conversation.message(payload, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
    return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
  });
});
```

You can use other languages (Python, curl, Java) see [this](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/) Documentation.

Check the example [here](http://conversation-simple.mybluemix.net/) running.